# Conditional column merging in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below datasets and need to left join df1 with df2 using id and Days based on below two conditions :-

**condition 1:**  if id and days are matching pick exact value from value column
**condition 2:**  if id is matching and day is not matching for that id then take average of all days of that id.

*for example:- For id 34 the value should be 3.5 (average of 3 and 4)*

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[12, 34, 56, 78], 'Days' :['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[12,12,34,34,56,56,56], 'Days' :['Sun', 'Mon', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Fri', 'Tue', 'Wed'], 'value':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
```

df1

```
    id  Days
0   12  Sun
1   34  Mon
2   56  Tue
3   78  Wed
```

df2

```
    id  Days value
0   12  Sun 1
1   12  Mon 2
2   34  Fri 3
3   34  Sat 4
4   56  Fri 5
5   56  Tue 6
6   56  Wed 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
# condition 1
out = df1.merge(df2, on=['id','Days'], how='left')
 
# condition 2   
out['value'] = out['value'].fillna(
    out['id'].map(df2.groupby('id')['value'].mean())
)
```

Output:

```
   id Days  value
0  12  Sun    1.0
1  34  Mon    3.5
2  56  Tue    6.0
3  78  Wed    NaN
```